# XPages: Navigating arround a document collection

Tags: java, xpages

I create a document collection and am able to put the docid of the second doc in the first doc, third in second and so till the last Document which enable me to navigate from first to second document when the user approved a job and so on, but i want to be also able to go from second back to first when the user reject the task but i have not be able to store the docid of the first in the second documnet. Below is the code i am currently using

```
Document nextJob= null;
Document thisJob =null;
DocumentCollection col = lookup.getAllDocumentsByKey(ID, true);
if (col != null){
Job= col.getFirstDocument();

while (job!= null) {
    thisJob.createDocument()
    thisJob =Job;
    thisJob.replaceItemValue("DocID",thisJob.getUniversalID());
    thisJob.save(true);
    if(nextJob!= null){
        nextJob.replaceItemValue("TaskSuccessor",thisJob.getUniversalID());
        nextJob.save(true);
    }
 nextJob= thisJob
 tmpDoc = Job;
 Job = col.getNextDocument(Job);
}
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to know the object type of currentTask (line 7).  currentJob looks like it is a NotesDocument, but you call createDocument() on it which is a method of the NotesDatabase class.

Comment: i have updated the question above i wabt to be able to store or save the UNID of the of the first Document in the second and the second in the third so that i could be able to move up and down in the workflow but with the above codein the documentcollection i could store the docid of the second document in the first and the third in the second and so on and the field TaskSuccessor holds the ID of the next

Comment: rethink your approach. do not store unids of documents inside the document. much better idea is to have the view or folder.

Comment: Modifying the documents whenever your collection changes is very bad practice, as it implies a lot of unneeded document changes and can result in massive amounts of save conflicts when the application is used by more than one person. Please explain, how this DocumentCollection is created and why you think you need to navigate through it like this...

Answer (score 1):

To echo Frantisek and others, updating the documents is not best practice. The key to how to achieve it is to consider a number of questions:

1. What you mean first next and previous job?
2. What is the numbers of jobs involved?
3. How are save conflicts going to be minimised / resolved by you / users?
4. How are deletions being handled, to ensure referential integrity?#
5. What happens when you need to archive data?

If it's for all users and next on date created, create a view based on date created. It will be quicker to create, completely negate the issue of save conflicts or deletes and not have a significant performance hit unless you're dealing with very large numbers of jobs (in which case you should be considering archiving).

If it's a small number of jobs, store them in a Java Map. But you need to handle deletions. Because you'll be loadingn the map when the app loads, archiving is not a problem.

If it's next / previous per user, a better method would be storing the order in a document per person in the database. If replicas are not involved, Note IDs can be used and will be shorter. It will negate save conflicts. But it may cause problems with large numbers of jobs - you will probably need to create new fields programmatically and also handle deletions.

DonMaro's suggestion fits with a graph database approach of edges (the third documents) between the vertices (the jobs).

In most cases, views will be the easiest and most recommended approach. IBM have included view index enhancements in 9.0.1 FP3 and will allow view indexes to be stored outside the NSF in the next point release.

Even if you're confident that you can build a better indexing system than what is already included in Domino, there are other aspects like save conflicts that need to be handled and you're decision may not allow future functional requirements like security, deletion, archiving etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i am working on a workflow. in the workflow document it has several job document which are response to the workflow document. so if the person responsible for particular job complete approve it the workflow is send to the next person responsible and if rejected it goes back to the previous and so on with a mail send to the person responsible

Comment: Document.responses() is what you want then. That will give a DocumentCollection of all the child documents (jobs) in date created order. It's using the internal response hierarchy table of the NSF, so you're not reinventing the wheel :-)

Comment: how do i go about the internal response hierarchy do u have any reference for me?

Comment: It's enabled by default. It can be turned off by going to Database Properties in Notes Client and ticking "Don't support specialized response hierarchy" on the last tab. But unless you've deselected that (and there's no point if you're using response documents), you get it out-of-the-box with Domino. Java method Document.getResponses() - NotesDocument.getResponses() in SSJS will get a collection of all responses to the relevant Document object.

Comment: the jobs are actually not a response to the worflow they are just categorise with the workflowdocID and i would like to access the previous and nextdocument in a particular category

Comment: The usual approach would be to use a categorised view sorted accordingly and navigate that. But the questions I've outlined to consider will allow you to have a more reasoned understanding of the impacts of navigating a collection of workflow jobs vs impacts of any additional application logic required if you use different documents or an "index" document per workflow document.

Answer (score 0):

Well, despite pointing out to really consider Frantisek Kossuth's comment (as UNIDs get changed in case you have might have to copy/paste a document back into the database, e.g. for backup; try considering generating unique values by using @Unique):
just create a third document object "prevJob" and store the previous document there when/before changing to the next one.
Then you can access the UNID just as you already do by "prevJob.getUniversalID()" and store it in the document you're currently processing.